# FactorMineR package in R saying N/A for R 3.6.1 (R3.6.1 "Action of Toes" / using RStudio Version 1.2.5019 / Ubuntu 18.04.3)

Tags: r, pca, install.packages

I am using the same version of R and RStudio on Windows 10. The FactorMineR package installs and works fine.

However, same thing but on Ubuntu: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘FactorMineR’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Any idea what is going on?  I am sort of new to R and Ubuntu. 
Thank you.

Comment: I can't see an `HCPC` package on CRAN. Do you mean function `HCPC` from `FactoMineR`? In that case, `install.packages("FactoMineR")` should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you, the posting has been corrected.

Comment: In that case, I've closed your question as a dupe of the linked target question. Please take a look at the extensive explanations and answers given in that post. If the issue remains, you should update your question to provide more details.